# Is there only one correct answer in heapsort?

Tags: sorting, binary-tree, heapsort

If starting with an empty heap representing a priority queue, where numbers have to be inserted in order and then represented as a binary tree, is there only one strict answer to that? I have tried different Java heap generators etc. and they are all giving me different answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the sorted representation, then it's obviously unique.

If you mean the binary tree representation, then yes it's unique too - a heap is a **complete tree** - binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible.

After all heap operations, may they be insert, delete-max, build-heap, siftup, siftdown, the heap remains in a predictable state, we **can** know how it's binary tree representation will look like.

Can you give more details about how you got different answers?